# Debugging MonoTouch in XamarinStudio stackTrace does not match break-points

Tags: ios, debugging, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I am developing an app in Xamarin Studio 4.0.4 and Xamarin.iOS 6.2.4.2 (Enterprise Edition). Until yesterday, I was developing and debugging fine. Today I have weird issues when debugging. I get a break points in files that I am not loading. For instance I load a View that is Called SplashScreen, but the debugger hits a point in InformationScreen (which is not loaded). When looking at the `CallStack`, It says that this point is in the LoginScreen which is again different.

[image]

Also, I am listening to the GPS Events and although I can see that the GPS is on and I am changing the Location on the Simulator, the debugger does not hit any breakpoint in the LocationDelegate, is this related?

Any help would be highly appreciated. I am debugging on physical iOS device that is running iOS 6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Xamarin.iOS 6.2.4.2

This is getting old now, unless you have a specific requirement, I'd recommend you upgrade to the latest stable version.

Your issue sounds like the debug information files (.mdb) have turned stale somehow - in this case the fix is to Clean & Rebuild your solution.

Comment: Thanks @Rolf, Have tried Clean & Build many times before posting. The reason I do not upgrade is every time I upgrade something stops working. Anyway, will give it a try and see.. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Rolf, I upgraded to the latest Xamarin.iOS but now I cannot build my app since it relies on some Resco Controls, and Resco does not support the latest Xamarin.iOS. Now I need to downgrade but cannot seem to do that. Is there a way to rollback to Xamarin.iOS 6.2.x?

Comment: Email contact@xamarin.com, they can provide you with links for earlier versions.

Comment: https://store.xamarin.com also has links to old versions if you log in to your account and then "manage your account"